# Convert flot bar chart from vertical to horizontal

Tags: jquery, bar-chart, flot

I'm using a vertical flot bar chart to display some users and two datasets for each user. Now I'm trying to make the chart horizontal but I can't seem to figure out how to put it together.

I have created a fiddle of the working vertical chart and simplified the data sets. https://jsfiddle.net/3oqu8Lzp/1/
I have tried setting

```
horizontal: true
```

on the bars and changing order in the datasets with no luck.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Check out : http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-horizontal-bar-chart.html

Comment: Thank you. Should have mentioned I already tried using that tutorial with no luck :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3oqu8Lzp/3/ this is what you want?

Comment: Well the labels are still placed wrong and the bars are overlapping. This was one of the problems I has too :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is very close to desired result https://jsfiddle.net/3oqu8Lzp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
    bars: {
      horizontal: true,
    },
```

to `options`. Updated demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/3oqu8Lzp/2/).